# How could the dogecoin increase the limit of money supply?

Tags: block, dogecoin, reward-schedule

As far as I know, Dogecoin will only have 100,000,000,000 coins in total. But how can the supply of coins remain uncapped? How could it produce unlimited dogecoins? Is there any specific skill to make the block provide unlimited coins?

Comment: why would you do that. the special thing about cryptocoins is that they have a limited amount of coins which saves it from inflation

Comment: Peercoin is an example of one with no limit on the number of coins (it's designed to have 1% inflation per year).

Comment: @Recall: Limited supply is in no way an inherent feature of cryptocurrency, it simply happens to be a design choice in some coins.  I believe most economists argue that some inflation is desirable,

Comment: I have something don't understand. They have already set up the quantity of coins per block, isn't it? But how could the dogecoin has unlimited coins in the future. Is it mean every coins can provide more coins in the future even they have already set up the system before?

Comment: possible duplicate: [Reward schedule and maximum number of dogecoins?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/19867/5406)

Answer (score 3):

The amount of bitcoins is not set by a hard coded limit, but indirectly through the rules of Bitcoin's reward schedule.
Bitcoin's reward started out at 100 bitcoins per block, and halves every 210,000 blocks (approximately four years) until the block reward drops to less than a [satoshi](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/117/5406) when it just stops.

On the other hand, Dogecoin's reward will only halve five times.
Then instead of halving again, it will go to a flat reward of 10k dogecoins indefinitely starting from Block 600,001. Therefore, it will continue to grow slowly without limit.

Also see my answer here: [Reward schedule and maximum number of dogecoins?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/19867/5406).

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin has a limited amount of coins too. They do that because the block reward is halved every 210000 blocks. If Dogecoin have something similar, then there is also a limited amount of Dogecoin. If you want unlimited amount of a certain cryptocoin (which is pointed out by Recall as something you don't want), you can for example not half the block reward.Then you'll get infinite amount of coins over time. However, this can **NOT** be done for a coin as bitcoin or dogecoin, as they already have a limited supply. It cannot be changed somehow. You have to make your own coin without limit (thanks Greg Hewgill)

See also the question [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/161/how-many-bitcoins-will-there-eventually-be), and especially the following equation:

[image: latex formula]

Comment: I think it's worth emphasising that you can't just *decide* to "not half the block reward" with an existing coin (that has limited supply). You would have to make your own coin with your own rules.

Comment: Actually it could be changed with a hardfork. But in this case the original Dogecoin client had an unintended feature of a flat reward after block 600,000. They decided not to fix it, thus it is not limited like Bitcoin.

Answer (score -2):

Dogecoin does not have a limit anymore.