# How many Dogecoin-satoshis will ever exist?

Tags: dogecoin, satoshi, reward-schedule

In Bitcoin, there will only ever be ~21,000,000 coins (slightly less, technically, but I'll just use 21 million for easy calculation). Each bitcoin is 10^8 satoshis. This means there be a maximum:

```
2,100,000,000,000,000 satoshis
```

- What is the equivalent number for Dogecoin?
- Is it larger than the maximum 64 bit unsigned integer?

Comment: This is a minor point of terminology, but the Dogecoin equivalent of Satoshi are called Koinu (romanized Japanese word for puppy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dogecoin has no maximum, [because it mints 10k dogecoins per block, forever](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/19867/reward-schedule-and-maximum-number-of-dogecoins).

But to answer the *spirit* of your question, there are 100 million indivisible parts to a dogecoin. You can see that [here](https://github.com/dogecoin/dogecoin/blob/65228644e10328172e9fa3ebe64251983e1153b3/src/util.h#L40).

```
static const int64_t COIN = 100000000;
```

There are currently 97 billion dogecoins. This is a bit more than 2^63 satoshis.

> Is it larger than the maximum 64 bit unsigned integer?

No, but it wouldn't matter if it was. There isn't a limit of 2^64 satoshis on the total money in Bitcoin (or altcoins). However, there is a limit of 2^64 satoshis *per output*.

Comment: Thanks, can you give a reference on the limit per output?

Comment: @StephenM347 It's not enforced anywhere in the code - but the [value field in outputs is an int64_t](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification#tx). There is also a [separate check](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/de8b9ab75718ef7663d5e8cc2f2135b8118730e7/src/main.cpp#L840) that the outputs are less than MAX_MONEY, but that can be changed pretty easily.